# Máscara JQuery que aceite valores até 10.0

Tags: jquery

Como eu faria para que um campo text recebesse valores até 10.0 e que tivesse uma máscara dessa forma: 1.0, 2.3, 10.0, ou seja, quando o valor for menor que o limite 10.0, o decimal ter apenas 1 número. Isso é possível com JQuery? Tenho um script que soma todos os campos, tem como incluir dentro desse script?

```
<input type='text' name='NotaI[]'  id='justificativa' class='mascara md-form-control'  value='".$notaProvas."'>
<input type='text' name='NotaII[]'  id='justificativa' class='mascara md-form-control'  value='".$notaProvas."'>
<input type='text' name='NotaIII[]'  id='justificativa' class='mascara md-form-control'  value='".$notaProvas."'>

<script>
     $("[name^='NotaI']").on("input", function(){

           var parent = $(this).closest("tr");

           var valorA = $("[name='NotaI[]']",parent).val() || 0;
           var valorB = $("[name='NotaII[]']",parent).val() || 0;
           var valorC = $("[name='NotaIII[]']",parent).val() || 0;

           var valor1 = parseFloat(valorA.toString().replace(',', '.'));
           var valor2 = parseFloat(valorB.toString().replace(',', '.'));
           var valor3 = parseFloat(valorC.toString().replace(',', '.'));

          /*
           var vazios = 0;

               $(":input.md-form-control").each(function(i, val) {
                  if ($(this).val() == '') {
                     vazios++;
                  }
               });
           console.log(matches);
         */
         var campos = $("[name^='NotaI']", parent);

          // conta apenas os vazios
          var vazios = campos.filter(function(){
              return $(this).val();
          }).length;

          var somar = ((valor1+valor2+valor3)/vazios).toFixed(1);
          $("[name='NotaFinal[]']", parent).val(somar);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: 10.0, poderia ser 10.01, 10.02, etc? Ou `10.0` é o limite, ou seja após o ponto fluante nada pode ser acima de `0`, mesmo que seja um numero bem "quebrado"?

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Isso, 10.0 seria o limite. Vou ajustar meu post ;)

Comment: Ele pode aceitar numeros como `9.99999998`?

Comment: Seria exatamente para nota escolar. Acredito que teria que ser 9.9 e 10.0.

Comment: Entendi, então a casa decimal é sempre de um digito, só preciso confirmar isto

Comment: isso mesmo. O decimal seria apenas 1 dígito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a casa decimal tem limite de um unico digito, você pode primeiramente usar `maxlength` no `<input>` de 4 dígitos (maior numero esperado é `10.0` - já que contém a "mascara") e em seguida aplicar uma função com regex bem simples.

No entanto o `input` é executado a todo momento, o que causa uma série de conflitos, eu sugiro optar pelo evento `blur`, que é só executado no momento que o elemento perder o foco, outra coisa importante é que para os inputs que já veem pré preenchidos é necessário executar a parte o evento, algo como:

```
$('[name^='NotaI']').each(function () {
    this.value //Aplica a mascara
});
```

```js
function mascaraPontoFlutuante(query, fixo, alvo) {
    var mascara;
    alvo = alvo || document;
    
    //Executa ao carregar a página
    $(function () {
       $(query, alvo).each(function () {
            trigger(this);
       });
    });
    
    //Atualiza quando o usuário tentar mudar o valor
    $(alvo).on("blur", query, function () {
        if (mascara) clearTimeout(mascara);
        
        mascara = setTimeout(trigger, 10, this);
    });
    
    function trigger(elemento) {
         var valor = elemento.value;
        //Se o formato estiver correto (regex) então não executa nada
        if (/^\d{1,2}\.\d$/.test(valor)) return;
        
        //Se o formato não for o esperado então ajusta
        
        //Remove tudo que não for numero ou ponto
        valor = parseFloat(valor.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""));

        //Se for um value vazio ele irá virar NaN, então isto transforma em 0
        if (isNaN(valor)) valor = 0;
        
        //Se o valor é maior que 10 então transforma em 10 novamente
        if (valor > 10) valor = 10;
        
        //Fixa o valor
        elemento.value = valor.toFixed(fixo);
    }
}

//Aplica a mascara e define o ponto fixo como 1
mascaraPontoFlutuante("[name^='NotaI']", 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='NotaI[]'  id='justificativa' class='mascara md-form-control'  value='1000' maxlength='4'>

<input type='text' name='NotaII[]'  id='justificativa' class='mascara md-form-control'  value='2' maxlength='4'>

<input type='text' name='NotaIII[]'  id='justificativa' class='mascara md-form-control'  value='9' maxlength='4'>
```

> - **Nota <sup>[1]</sup>:** O terceiro parametro `alvo` é opicional, ele serve para acaso você queira isolar o evento para um elemento especifico, tipo, suponha que existem 2 grupos de elementos ou que você queira aplicar a mascara em um elemento dentro de um IFRAME, basta ajustar essa terceira variavel.
> - **Nota <sup>[2]</sup>:** O `setTimeout` para quem não entende, neste é usado para evitar que muitos eventos (que podem ocorrer devido a outros scripts) executem repetidas vezes o `trigger`, ou seja, com o `clearTimeout`+`setTimeout` ele vai garantir que dentro do intervalo de 10ms seja só executado uma vez, assim desta forma evitando execuções paralelas.
> - **Nota <sup>[3]</sup>:** observe que apliquei o `maxlength` para evitar a pessoa digitar muita coisa.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme.